# Overleaf - Included sty and other input package files common across all my projects

Tags: texmf, overleaf, texinputs

When an ordinary user specifies `TEXINPUTS` in Overleaf [e.g., as illustrated [here](https://www.overleaf.com/help/212-i-have-a-lot-of-cls-sty-bst-files-and-i-want-to-put-them-in-a-folder-to-keep-my-project-uncluttered-but-my-project-is-not-finding-them-to-compile-correctly#.VrxZJViLTDc)] is there a concept of a ".." directory above the current Project? The reason I would like to be able to do that is that I have image files, defs, and so on that I want to be able to draw on across all my Overleaf Projects, and I would prefer not to create separate copies of them to put in a `./includes//:` inside whichever current Project I happen to be working.

To be clear, in my local texlive usage for those shared files I just use texmf/ in my login directory, but Overleaf of course doesn't have the notion of "my login directory". Or does it?

Comment: No -- each Overleaf project is a separate Docker (mini) container, so they can't see each other. Having said that, you can use the "Add files > File from other project" in the Overleaf top bar to share files between projects.

Comment: When you "Add files" that way, are they physically copied over into the Docker container, or a fresh copy somehow instantiated? If so, then this isn't really a solution as I typically want changes in the originals to propagate throughout. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: they're actually linked/aliased files, but updates are not propagated automatically. You'll have to click on the "Refresh" option for each linked child file, every time there's an "upstream" change, to retrieve and apply the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No – each Overleaf project is a separate Docker (mini) container, so they can't see each other. Having said that, you can use the "Add files > File from other project" in the Overleaf top bar to share files between projects.

These would become linked/aliased files, but updates are not propagated automatically. You'll have to click on the "Refresh" option for each linked child file, every time there's an "upstream" change, to retrieve and apply the changes.