# How to maintain macros file both locally and on Overleaf

Tags: macros, packages, overleaf, texmf

I want to share a .sty file between documents locally.

I push my local changes to Overleaf often. It is crucial that the document can always be compiled on Overleaf with the current version of the .sty file.

Does there exist a solution which does not require me to open Overleaf after updating the .sty file?

I know these questions, and none of the answers are satisfactory:

[How to maintain macros file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279714/how-to-maintain-macros-file)

[Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te?rq=1)

[Overleaf - Included sty and other input package files common across all my projects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292318/overleaf-included-sty-and-other-input-package-files-common-across-all-my-proje)

Comment: This is a good question for Overleaf support (disclaimer, I work for Overleaf support). You can push to the project anytime, but it sounds like you want to programatically trigger a compile and get a report back. Overleaf does not offer a public API for that currently. Sorry for the limitation. Please feel free to get in touch if that is not what you were asking about, if you have other questions, or if you have suggestions to improve the service: https://www.overleaf.com/contact.

Comment: I don't need to trigger a compile, I just want to have my .sty in my local texmf/ somehow synced with all of my Overleaf documents. I figured out maybe a bash script that copies the .sty file on pushing to Overleaf may do the job. Thanks for the reply!