# How to share multiple files from another project in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, folders

I have over a hundred .png figures that exist within a folder in an Overleaf project that I would like to use in another project. I know to transfer files across projects is to click:

"Upload > From Another Project > Select a Project + Select a File".

However, "Select a File" only allows me to choose individual files, which would take ages if there are many. May I ask is there a way to transfer multiple files at once, or better, to transfer an entire folder between two projects?

Comment: that was asked here the other day, the easiest way is probably download your whole project then upload teh files to the new one (you can select multiple files in the upload form) alternatively if the new project is new start from a copy of your old project and delete the files you don't want after the copy

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Sharing an entire folder of files across projects in one go isn't possible at the moment, sorry for the limitation there. I'll pass the feedback along to our product team to consider for the future.

Comment: Related question: [texmf - Overleaf - Included sty and other input package files common across all my projects - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292318/overleaf-included-sty-and-other-input-package-files-common-across-all-my-proje)

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the project which contains the pictures you want to upload.
2. Now in the project in which you want to add the pictures, click on upload, locate the pictures and drag & drop all the pictures into the upload section.