# Automatically refresh files uploaded from another overleaf project

Tags: overleaf

I have several *application* projects (e.g., `project1`) which use common files (macro definitions, etc.)
I created a `common` project to hold those files, and uploaded the files from `project1`, which sets a link to the files.

As of now, whenever the files in `common` change, in `project1` I have to update the links one by one, which becomes annoying.
To work more efficiently across projects, I mean to:

1. Have an automatic update of the links in `project1` whenever the files in `common` change. In the absence of this feature, at least...
2. ... update all the links manually in `project1`, but with a single operation, e.g., by something like selecting all links and updating.

**Is that possible?**

PS: I don't have the paid version.

**Related**:

1. [How to share multiple files from another project in Overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603483/how-to-share-multiple-files-from-another-project-in-overleaf)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I suspect this may be more readily answered by Overleaf support.

Comment: I suspect it is a duplicate of the post you mention. I think with the paid for version you could link your projects to a shared git repo, but otherwise you need to copy each file separately

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - No, it is not a dupe. I have already uploaded files from another project, which is different from what solutions to the other OP suggest. And I know the paid version allows for git connection. But that would not solve my question, even if it is very useful per se. Thanks.

Comment: May I know whether you have found the solution on this matter? I am facing the same problem, it would be very helpful if you have the solution to share. Thank you.

Comment: On Overleaf, do you have a paid account? Do you know how to use `git`? If so, a git `submodule` might be a solution.

Comment: @PaulGaborit - No, I don't. Question updated.

Comment: @HengJie - If I find a solution, I will post it.

Comment: In your Overleaf project, you can upload a file from another Overleaf project (via the `upload` button). Then the "uploaded" file keeps a link to the original file and can be refreshed at any time (by selecting it and using the `refresh` button). But it's not automatic...

Comment: @PaulGaborit - I am not seeing if your comment provides any hint to alleviate the "issue" referred to in the OP... would you mind clarifying? Thanks!

Comment: After rereading the question, I understand that you already use the linked files between different Overleaf projects. My second comment brings nothing new. What's missing in Overleaf is an automatic update or one-shot update for a set of linked files.